# Why can't the compiler (gcc) recognise and diagnose a destructor missing a definition?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors

I spent too much time diagnosing a strange (yet, in hindsight, pretty straightforward) linker error that ended up being because a destructor in my base class was defined as:

```
~SomeClass();
```

instead of

```
~SomeClass(){};
```

in the .h file. This seems like it should be incredibly easy for a compiler to recognise compared to some other weird things I've seen it diagnose, yet for me it only generated linker errors.

Additional data: I use CMake, and gcc as a compiler.

Comment: Please take some time to learn about the difference between *declarations* and *definitions*. `~SomeClass();` is a *declaration*, it tells the compiler that the destructor is *defined* (actually implemented) in some other [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). If the actual definition is missing, then the linker will complain.

Comment: It'd perfectly valid (and sometimes necessary) to define destructor out of class.

Comment: As for your example, if you don't need a specific body for the destructor function, then I would recommend you *default* the destructor, as `~SomeClass() = default;` The compiler will then make sure that there is a definition (implementation) of the destructor.

Comment: Answer in the dupe explains that: "Object files can refer to symbols that are not defined. This is the case when you use a declaration, and don't provide a definition for it. The compiler doesn't mind this, and will happily produce the object file as long as the source code is well-formed."

Comment: when a function is never used no definition is required. The compiler cannot know for sure if a function is never used.

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that you intended to not just declare the constructor? There is (at least almost) never any reason to define an empty destructor, so it would actually make more sense to warn about the code you intended.

Comment: Because it's a linker error, not a compiler error. The compiler can't see what other source files you're going to compile, or what other object files you're going to link with.

Comment: The simplest thing to do with a definition like `~SomeClass(){};` is to remove it. It serves no purpose and with no destructor declared or defined there is no problem. If you are following best practise it's actually quite rare to write a class that needs a destructor.

Comment: Sorry if my questions are nonsense, but what is the difference between just declaring a function that is never defined or used like `void some_function();` and a destructor that is never defined or used, like `~SomeClass();`? One generates a linker error, the other one does not. Am I actually calling the destructor somehow, or does the linker recognise that I must in fact do it? I'm sorry if this is covered in the dupe (I did read it). 

And thank you so much for responding. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: If you declare a function but never call it, there doesn't need to be a definition because it will never be called. But all objects needs a destructor, it will always be called once an object is destructed after all. If you *don't* declare a destructor the compiler will create one for you. But if you *do* declare a destructor, the compiler will assume that you want to define it as well, and won't create a definition.

Comment: ~SomeClass(); is perfectly cromulent C++. There's absolutely nothing with that that a C++ compiler has any reason to complain about. The only possible time where this error can be detected is at the linking stage. Which is what happened here. Can you explain how you expected your C++ compiler to telepathically determine that the destructor will not be defined in any C++ translation unit that will get compiled in the future, after this one gets compiled?

Comment: I found it funny rather than condescending.